# javascript/jquery: replace operator !== 0 with > 0 possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

I'm wondering:

I have a formula that checks **if something !== 0**

If I'm sure something cannot be negativ, can I replace **!== 0** with **> 0** and always get the same result?

Comment: Yes, *if you're sure that the number in question will never be negative*

Comment: Yes, if we assume `typeof something === 'number' && !isNaN(something)`.

Comment: (Or, to put duri's comment another way:) Undefined values and non-numerical values (like empty strings) won't give you the same result. Hopefully you're testing for those, too.

Comment: How are you checking for negative?

Comment: Also, what do you want this condition to represent to a human that reads it?

Comment: @paulbutcher: I want to change this:   If (something < 0 || something !== 0) {}   To this: if (something < 0 || something > 0). If I' m sure something won't be zero, I could do it like that, could I?

Comment: Your first condition is redundant.  Something that is less than zero will always be inequal to zero.  Why not just `if (something !==0)`?  What I'm really asking, is what you would want someone to think if they were reading it out.  Do you want them to think "is something non-zero" or "does something have a higher value than zero"?  Also, what do you hope to gain from this change?

Comment: The actual condition is more complex and from a plugin I'm trying to modify. Like this: _if ( something < 0 || A && something !== 0 ) )_ which I changed to this: _if ( something < 0 && ( not:B || not:C ) ||  ( A || D || B || C  ) && something > 0 )_. Still trying to find out if everything is working according to plan though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if and only if that value is not negative. But JavaScript is a language that is difficult to make such assertions.

Answer (score 0):

No.

`"0" !== 0` is true

`"0"  > 0` is false

Answer (score -1):

There is a === in javascript

so if x = 5

then x === 5 is true
but x === '5' is false

but for == both will return true.